# Calculate e^x and ln(x)

Tags: code-golf, math

Given a floating point `x` (`x<100`), return [`e^x`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) and [`ln(x)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm). The first 6 decimal places of the number have to be right, but any others after do not have to be correct.

You cannot have any "magic" constants explicitly stated (e.x. `a=1.35914` since `1.35914*2 ~= e`), but you can calculate them. Only use `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` for arithmetic operators.

If x is less than or equal to 0, output `ERROR` instead of the intended value of ln(x).

Test Cases:

```
input: 2
output: 7.389056 0.693147
input: 0.25
output: 1.284025 -1.386294
input: 2.718281828
output: 15.154262 0.999999  (for this to output correctly, don't round to 6 places)
input: -0.1
output: 0.904837 ERROR
```

Shortest code wins.

Comment: I assume you mean to exclude exponentiation of entirely (not just for the the calculation of e itself)? `2**(x*1.442695)` for example seems a bit too easy.

Comment: @primo: yes, there is no exponentiation whatsoever, but things like `product([2]*3)` is ok. I guess I should rule out "magic constants" in the case of `1.442695`.

Comment: You might want to also specify a valid range for the input - any approximation can lose accuracy if `x` becomes too large or too small.

Comment: @A.R.S.: added a boundary. Thanks.

Comment: maybe a lower bound too? something like 1e-2 < abs(x) < 1e2 since most evaluations seem to be losing accuracy for abs(x) < 1e-2 (unless you want that to be part of the challenge?)

Comment: @milest: That will be part of the challenge. It should not be very hard to implement, since most answers are approximations.

Comment: No one uses APL!? Seriously?

Comment: I'm not sure why the accepted answer was changed. Perl 89 is shorter than Javascript 90, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript, <strike>103</strike> <strike>101</strike> <strike>99</strike> <strike>97</strike> <strike>93</strike> 90

This implementation is based on primo's comprehensive description of the algorithm he used.

```
for(e=l=x=prompt(g=1e5);--g;y=x-1,l=(x>1?y/=x:-y)*l+y/g)
    e=1+e/g*x;
alert([e,x>0?l:"ERROR"])
```

Edit:
- Trying to catch Perl. Stole a byte back from primo by copying his branch. :)
- 2 more bytes courtesy of primo.
- Finally, caught primo's version! With primo's help, of course... :)
- Simplified the assignment to L. Shaved 3 more bytes.

Comment: It's somewhat humorous that defining `Math.abs` inline is actually shorter than using the built-in.

Comment: As far as catching perl goes, would it help if I pointed out that the initial values of `e` and `l` don't really matter?

Comment: @primo Nice catch!

Comment: I've got 93, by combining the `y` and `l` definitions: `l=(x>1?y=1-1/x:-(y=x-1))*l+y/g`

Comment: Very elegant. I probably spent over an hour trying to figure out a way to exploit the relationship between `x<1` and `y<0`. You sir, are a genius! :)

Comment: Nice! I'd +1 again if I could!

Answer (score 10):

### PHP <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```
<?for($g=1e4;--$g;$l=$y/$g+abs($y=$x>1?1-1/$x:$x-1)*$l)$e=1+$e/$g*$x.=fgets(STDIN);echo"$e ",$x>0?$l:ERROR;
```

\$e^x\$ is a fairly straight-forward calculation. I use a nested form of the sum of inverse factorials, which not only increases the convergence rate, but also allows for exponentiation at the same time:

$$e^x = 1 + x \left( 1 + \frac x 2 \left( 1 + \frac x 3 \left( 1 + \frac x 4 \bigg( 1 + \dots \bigg)\right)\right)\right)$$

\$\ln x\$ is slightly more complicated. All convergent series seem to work for \$x \le 1\$ or \$x \ge 1 \$, but not both (Newton's iteration does not have this limitation, but requires the calculation of \$e^{x_n}\$ each step). This isn't really a problem, though, given the log identity:

$$\ln x = -\ln \frac 1 x$$

This means that if, for example, the iteration you're using only works on \$0 < x \le 1\$ and \$x > 1\$, you can use the multiplicative inverse of \$x\$ and negate the result. Because I was using a nested identity for \$e^x\$, I also chose to use a nested identity for \$\ln x\$:

$$\ln(1 + x) = x\left(1 - x\left(\frac 1 2 - x\left(\frac 1 3 - x\left(\frac 1 4 - \dots \right)\right)\right)\right)$$

where \$0 < x \le 1\$

Or equivalently, as demonstrated by [Paul Walls' implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9080/calculate-ex-and-lnx/9097#9097):

$$\ln(1 + x) = x - x\left(\frac x 2 - x\left(\frac x 3 - x\left(\frac x 4 - \dots \right)\right)\right)$$

I define the \$0 < x \le 1\$ case as \$x-1\$ (which is necessarily negative), using the absolute value for the inner product, and then allowing a bare \$x\$ value in the fraction to correct the sign.

Sample I/O:

```
$ echo 2 | php exp_ln.php
7.3890560989307 0.69314718055995

$ echo 0.25 | php exp_ln.php
1.2840254166877 -1.3862943611199

$ echo 2.718281828 | php exp_ln.php
15.154262234523 0.99999999983113

$ echo -0.1 | php exp_ln.php
0.90483741803596 ERROR
```

---

### Perl <s>95</s> <s>93</s> 89 bytes

```
$e=1+$e/$?*($x.=<>),$l=$_/$?+$l*abs,$_=$x>1?1-1/$x:$x-1while--$?;print"$e ",$x>0?$l:ERROR
```

Nearly identical to the PHP solution above, with a slightly larger iteration (`65535` down to `0`).

Edits:

- Both 2 byte improvements due to Paul Walls.
- Four more bytes saved in Perl by (ab)using `$?`, which is stored internally as an unsigned short, and by using `$_` to save parentheses in `abs`.

Comment: For x = 1e-4, I get php "1.0001000050002 -8.9909564381939" and perl "1.00010000500017 -8.99099322429857". Should be like "1.000100005 -9.21034037195" Anyways nice job taking advantage of ln x = -ln 1/x to use a nested expression

Comment: @milest `x=1e-5` will be off by even more, because it's the same calculation as `x=100000`. As it is, `x=1e-2` and `x=100` are accurate to full floating point precision, and `x=1e-3` and `x=1000` are accurate to about 5 digits. If more accuracy is needed, the arbitrary `1e4` bound that I've chosen can be increased accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2 (168 char)

basic implementation of power series

I need to learn a golfing language =/

I increased the bound to 1e-14 (twice from 1e-7) since some values were off a bit in 6 decimal places, works well for input from 1e-5 to 100 (slows down at input approaches 0)

```
x=input();t,r,i=1,0,1.
while abs(t)>=1e-14:t,r,i=t*x/i,r+t,i+1
if x<=0:s='Error'
else:z=(x-1.)/(x+1);t,s,i=2*z,0,1
while abs(t/i)>=1e-14:t,s,i=t*z*z,s+t/i,i+2
print r,s
```

Comment: Doesn't python support `m=1e-7`?

Comment: yes it does but 1e-7 can be thought of as 1*10^-7 which might be thought of as exponentiation, so I'm not really sure if its allowed here

Comment: I will allow for scientific notation.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 166 (89 without I/O)

```
s=1e-7
e x|x>s=1/e(-x)|x>0=1+x|y<-e$x+s=y-y*s
l x|x<1=0-l(1/x)|1>0=sum$map(s/)[1,1+s..x]
n x|x<0="ERROR"|1>0=show$l x
main=interact$unwords.(\x->[show$e x,n x]).read
```

Takes an alternative approach: we use that

*∂/∂x e<sup>x</sup>* = *e<sup>x</sup>*

and solve the differential equation numerically, with a simple euler method. Similarly, use

ln *x* = <sub>1</sub>*∫<sup>x</sup>* 1/*x* d‌*x*

and calculate the integral with the rectangular method.

Example:

> $ echo 2 | ./exp-and-log
>   7.389056835370484 0.6931472554471929
>   $ echo 0.25 | ./exp-and-log 
>   1.284025432730133 -1.3862944228194163
>   $ echo 2.718281828 | ./exp-and-log 
>   15.15426430695358 1.0000000576151333
>   $ echo -0.1 | ./exp-and-log 
>   0.9048374135134576 ERROR

It's quite amazingly inefficient, in fact it uses about 4 GB of memory even for these examples (since it's non-tail–recursive... you need to compile (in GHC) with `-with-rtsopts=-K2G` so it even accepts such a ridiculous stack size).

Answer (score 1):

## R (101 bytes)

Note that $$e^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n.$$ Then, for large enough n, we can approximate e by a product.

```r
n=1e+08;prod(rep(1+x/n,n))
```

Similarly, note that $$\log(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt \leq \Delta t \cdot \sum \frac{1}{t+\Delta t}$$

```r
dt=0.1;sign(x-1)*sum((1/seq(min(1,x),max(1,x),by=dt))*dt))
```

Combined into one **answer** (80 bytes):

```r
n=1e+08;c(prod(rep(1+x/n,n)),sign(x-1)*sum((1/seq(min(1,x),max(1,x),by=1/n))/n))
```

Will produce `-Inf` instead of `ERROR` in case `x < 0`.

```r
[1] 7.3890560 0.6931472
[1]  1.284025 -1.386294
[1] 15.15426  1.00000
[1] 0.9048374      -Inf
```

---

Or, with the `ERROR` handling, `101 bytes`:

```r
n=1e+08;gsub("-Inf","ERROR",c(prod(rep(1+x/n,n)),sign(x-1)*sum((1/seq(min(1,x),max(1,x),by=1/n))/n)))
```

```r
[1] "7.38905602540599"  "0.693147188059945"
[1] "1.28402541433558"  "-1.38629438611989"
[1] "15.154261581541"  "1.00000000372749"
[1] "0.904837420549773" "ERROR"
```

Comment: A TIO link would be great.