# exponential without exponential

Tags: code-golf

Your goal is to calculate the exponential of a float (e**x) up to 2 decimal places for any float within 1 to 10. The accepted error range is 0.01.

However, you must not use the built-in exponential function or the logarithm function.

In fact, attempts to circumvent this by `(2**x)**(1/ln(2))` are prohibited, even if you hardcode the ln(2).

Basically, the power function is fine, as long as the index is not derived from the input.

Shortest solution in bytes wins.

(You may include an extra solution which uses the built-in, but which does not affect the score in any way.)

### Specs

- Program or function
- Any reasonable input/output format

### Testcases

```
1 -> 2.71 or 2.72 or 2.73
```

Comment: `you must not use the built-in exponential function` would seem to collide with `the power function is fine`

Comment: x** 3 is allowed while 3**x is not.

Comment: What about `3 ^ 3`, or `x ^ y`>? (I'm not suggesting hardcoding the output, I just don't get the difference)

Comment: The index cannot be any function of the input.

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35732/raise-to-the-power)

Comment: Does `float` imply 32bit floats, namely the range `-3.4E+38 to +3.4E+38`?

Comment: We've calculated e^x and ln(x) before. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9080/calculate-ex-and-lnx/9081

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 17 bytes

```
@(x)(1+x/1e9)^1e9
```

Comment: I'm deeply confused as to why this works.

Comment: `exp(x) = limit (1+x/n)^n as n->infinity`. As long as you only have a fixed range you just need to choose `n` big enough.

Comment: OH. Welp. My Taylor series workings out are now useless. xD

Comment: The talyor series are also quite well known `exp(x) = sum x^n / n! for n=0 upto inftinity`, converges everywhere.

Comment: Well, yeah - I meant porting it to AS.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 19 bytes

```
(**1e9).(1+).(/1e9)
```

or alternatively a named function:

```
f x=(1+x/1e9)**1e9
```

Answer (score 0):

## AppleScript, 204 bytes

```
set x to(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned
set r to 1
set i to 1
repeat 29
set r to r+(x^i)/f(i)
set i to i+1
end
return r
on f(a)
set x to a
repeat x-1
set a to a-1
set x to a*x
end
x
end
```

Yeah, it's kinda long. This uses the 30th term Taylor polynomial representation for e^x.

#### How this works:

The Taylor series expansion for e<sup>x</sup> is:

[image: taylor]

Now, according to the Lagrange error bound, I know that any given Taylor polynomial can get a precision to the first unused term of the Taylor series.

In more mathematical terms, I know that:

[image: power]

where I will have a precision to e<sup>x</sup> of a<sub>k+1</sub>.

Since the OP specified that I must have a precision of 2 decimal places or better, a<sub>k+1</sub> must be less than or equal to 1/100. I need to work out the point at which the maximum error of the function possible, located at 10 in this case is less than said error. After a little trial and error, I found that:

[image: precision]

Which means that:

[image: final]

For as far as our precision is concerned. The code reflects this in that I will calculate:

[image: calculated sum]

Answer (score 0):

## AppleScript, 62 bytes

Okay, limit approximation of e<sup>x</sup> is better. ;P Thanks, flawr.

```
(1+(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned/1e9)^1e9
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 9 bytes

```
1e9/Q1e9^
```

Based upon @flawr's answers.

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MWU5L1ExZTle&input=MQ)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a number
1e9     % Number literal
/       % Divide the input by 1e9
Q       % Add one
1e9     % Number literal
^       % Exponent
        % Implicitly display result
```